# Open corrupted Word document in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am developing an application to convert word document to pdf. It's working fine but in case when the word document is corrupted and says "file is in use" and give 3 choices. In that area the application failed.

This is how I open the Word document.

```
wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(
                              ref paramSourceDocPath, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                              ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref objWordVisible,
                              ref objOpenAndRepair, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                              ref paramMissing);
```

This is how I export to PDF:

```
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFilePath, paramExportFormat, paramOpenAfterExport, paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage, paramEndPage, paramExportItem, paramIncludeDocProps, paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks, paramDocStructureTags, paramBitmapMissingFonts, paramUseISO19005_1,ref paramMissing);
```

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: A file doesn't have to be corrupted to be in use...

Comment: If the file is corrupt, it's corrupt. Can you open it in Word at all?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when i open that word it opens a dialogbox saying "File in Use" and gives 3 option like 1. open in read only, 2. copy file for modification, 3. i dont remember. if i give read only then its opens. so its valid only but currupted by some application or not properly closed.

Comment: Microsoft has offered the ability for Word to be converted to a PDF document since Office 2007.  It seems like a much better idea to use that feature if its an option.

Comment: @Mukesh - Unless you go and check what happens when you attempt to open the document in "read-only mode" we cannot help you.  It seems the simply solution is to delete the lock file.

Comment: yes. but that is not an issue. i have problem in opening the word files. i have to do with open word document.

Comment: @Mukesh - Please try my suggestion and report back.

Comment: s i can open that file in "read-only" mode

Comment: Then it's not corrupted.  Try logging out and logging back in again, if another program is using it, that will close it.

Answer (score 0):

If the document is in use by another application, make a [copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) of the file and then open the copy.  Then you should be able to exclusively open it and perform your operations.

Comment: but this application is going to handle lacs and lacs file. so when i do copy, then it increases the IO operation and also the disk size